# Travis-CI build is failing due to CompileSwift build command failures

Tags: ios, xcode, travis-ci

While building an iOS project on Travis-CI, I am getting multiple build command failures like:-

**Testing failed:
Use of undeclared type 'SomeClassCancelDelegate'

Use of undeclared type 'SomeClassPaymentCell'

Use of undeclared type 'SomeClassPaymentCell'

Use of unresolved identifier 'SomeViewController'

Command CompileSwift failed with a nonzero exit code

Testing cancelled because the build failed.**

** TEST FAILED **

**The following build commands failed:
    CompileSwift normal x86_64 /Users/travis/build/some-Group/someproject-ios/Modules/SubModules/SomeViewControllerExtensions.swift**

Is there a way to configure .yml file so that Travis will ignore such failures and let the build succeed?

Thanks a lot in advance for your help!

Answer (score 1):

Finally figured it out, it was an issue with the unit test cases of the project. While executing the build command, unit tests also gets build which were failing in my case and hence, failing the overall build.